# Gauss Law Question. Could anyone explain to me why does S3 is 0 in this lecture note example?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

Why does S3 equal to 0 ? for E3 dot dA = 0?

Could I also know why does dA1 and dA2 point up and down? while dA3 point to the right?

Comment: The electric-field component is exactly zero in the direction of normal to the area vector for $S_3$.

Comment: @Aniket I think you should have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @YogeshYadav Okay as you say. I'll post this as an answer and delete the comment.

Comment: I want to echo what user3257624 says below about language. *"Why does S3 equal to 0 ?"* is a poor question. Firstly because $S_3$ is a surface not a number, and secondly because the text *doesn't* say that $S_3$ is zero. The text says there is "no contribution [to the total flux] at $S_3$". You should to fill in the part I put in []s from the context of the problem. I image this seems like pedantic nit picking to you (it often does to my students) but it is only by being careful about these sorts of thing that you will learn to do physics.

Comment: Precisely! However, it would have a meaning, by abuse of language, if it would refer to a surface with zero area.

Answer (score 2):

"$S_3$ equal to zero" is a meaningless expression: $S_3$ is the cylindrical surface of your "pill box". And $E_3\cdot\ dA_3$ is zero because $E_3$ (the electric field calculated on $S_3$) is vertical to the normal vector of $S_3$, i.e. $dA_3$

Answer (score 1):

Electric field lines flow from positive to negative charge. So they originate from the sheet and move upwards and downwards. The surface $S_3$ has its normal directed perpendicular to the electric field lines. So, flux through the surface = $\phi_3 = \int \vec E_3\cdot\vec {dA_3} = E_3 A_3 \cos 90 = 0$. Hope it helps.