# Gauss Law Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

Why is ${\rm d}\vec{A}_1$ pointing up and ${\rm d}\vec{A}_2$ pointing down?

Electric field ${\rm d}\vec{E}_1$ is pointing up so isn't it supposed to be perpendicular to the surface?

Comment: Exact copy of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/209080/

Comment: Hi KL DC. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Answer (score 3):

Direction of area is in the direction of the normal drawn outwards. Direction of the area and the plane of area are at right angles.